# How would I find these grades and these class names using mechanize and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, urllib

So, I've figured out how to login in to the website that allows me to check my grades, progress book, with python, mechanize, and BeautifulSoup. But I've run into a problem with getting the name of classes and the grades from the html page. Here is one of the classes and Grades:

```
< a class="expandable-row" href="/student/assignments/class/16152? 

< span class="expandable-row">85.42 B< /span>
```

So, I need to python to search through the html to find all the classnames and all the grades.
Here is the full html code: http://pastebin.com/ikaw0FmN
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post some code if you've written it. No ones going to just do this for you but they will correct what you've tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you know how to grab the page with requests you would do the following:

```
...
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...  

gradetd = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('td',{'class':'fixed-column important'})

for row in gradetd:
    grades = row.find('span',{'class':'expandable-row'}).text.strip()
    if grades:
        avg, grade = grades.split(' ')
        print("{}/{}".format(avg,grade))



89.83/A-
99.14/A+
98.20/A+
91.14/A-
94.32/A
95.76/A
91.28/A-
85.42/B
97.86/A+
95.63/A
90.16/A-
94.09/A
97.02/A+
92.64/A-
100.00/A+
100.00/A+
100.00/A+
98.18/A+
100.00/A+
```